# Angularjs multiple 'OR' conditions not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When i check for more than 2 'OR' conditions in ng-disabled it does not work.

The below code does not work properly

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="correctProperty()" ng-disabled="entityPropertyForm.$pristine || propertyCorrected || dropDownChanged">Save</button>
```

The below two conditions works perfectly.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="correctProperty()" ng-disabled="propertyCorrected || dropDownChanged">Save</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="correctProperty()" ng-disabled="entityPropertyForm.$pristine || propertyCorrected">Save</button>
```

Why I could not check the 3rd condition and only 2 conditions work perfectly ? I tried few other suggestions like "http://jsfiddle.net/8bc24nau/1/"

Comment: Why not try to bind these 2 conditions to a single variable, then test against that 1 variable? It would solve the problem. Also, could you be more specific when you say 'it doesn't work'; What does this mean? What error are you getting? If that 1 condition does not work, it's more than likely a problem with either your syntax or that property itself

Comment: Have you tried checking each condition individually against a test sample? It would at least clear up knowing whether or not all conditions meet with a `true` or `false`

Comment: i tried with each condition seperately, it works fine.

Comment: @SGN Then please create a plunkr or a fiddle that demonstrates the incorrect behavior.  The code you've posted should work just fine.

Comment: when i say it does not work, it means the button is disabled when it is not supposed to.

Comment: maybe you can create a function in the scope say enable() that returns OR of the conditions you want to check and use it for ng-disabled

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use `<pre>` tag in order to make sure that you are getting the write values for each field. 
I've added it to your jsfiddle example:

```
<div ng-app>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mt0">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mt1">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mt2">
    <pre>mt0={{mt0}}</pre>
    <pre>mt1={{mt1}}</pre>
    <pre>mt2={{mt2}}</pre>
    <button ng-disabled="(mt0||mt1||mt2)">Reassign</button>
</div>
```

Comment: While decent troubleshooting steps, in and of itself it's not an answer.

Comment: The question wasn't clear enough so I've answered with a debugging technique.